# /manager/html in tomcat installation not accessible

Tags: debian, tomcat

I just installed tomcat 6 in Debian 6 with the `apt-get`:

```
apt-get install tomcat6 tomcat6-common tomcat6-docs tomcat6-admin tomcat6-user
```

After that, http://localhost:8080 is accessible without any problems, also the jsp and servlet examples run as expected.

To be able to access the /manager/html area, I edited the file $CATALINA_HOME/skel/conf/tomcat-users.xml, now it looks like this:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<tomcat-users>
   <role rolename="manager" />
   <role rolename="admin" />
   <role rolename="tomcat" />
   <user username="tomcat" password="secret" roles="tomcat,admin,manager" />
</tomcat-users>
```

After that, I restarted tomcat with:

```
/etc/init.d/tomcat6
```

When I try to access http://localhost:8080/manager/html and enter "tomcat" : "secret" into the htaccess-box, I get "Access denied". Why this? Is there anything else I have to do?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The role you need to access WEB admin interface is called **manager-gui**. It is sufficient to add these two lines to ***/etc/tomcat6/tomcat-users.xml*** (within *tomcat-users* tag):

```
<role rolename="manager-gui"/>
<user username="tomcat" password="secret" roles="manager-gui"/>
```

and restart the server.

Comment: Thank you for pointing me to the correct file! Now it is working

Comment: @strauberry: although not question related, i'd also suggest installing tomcat native library (it will speed-up it noticeably) if you haven't done it already (just `apt-get install libtcnative-1`, tomcat will grab it automatically upon restart).